# How can I represent dates in a different way?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a column DT, which contains dates in a format like this: 01-FEB-22 and etc

How can I write sql script, which would display the dates like shown in DT_n column:

| DT | DT_N |
| --- | --- |
| 01-FEB-22 | 22 FEB |
| 01-JAN-22 | 22 JAN |
| 01-DEC-21 | 21 DEC |

Also, I need to order DT_n in chronological order, latest month and year should be the last.

I have next SQL script for the last 12 months:

```
SELECT ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE,'MM'), 
       1-(LEVEL)) AS DT,
       LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE,'MM'), 1-(LEVEL))) AS DT_LAST_DAY
FROM DUAL 
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 12
```

Comment: Your DT column doesn't store any format information, just the date. You can format it how you want, or leave it to the instance/session/client/desktop defaults.

Answer (score 3):

Just use `to_char()`.

```
SELECT dt,
       to_char(dt, 'YY MON') dt_n
       FROM elbat;
```

Comment: The format string should have been 'YY MON'

Comment: @userMT: True. Copied the wrong one. Corrected. Thanks.